# Как применить функцию jquery к определенному элементу?

Tags: jquery

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатие на конкретную кнопку только у нее одной появлялся класс "white-btn-active", а у той кнопки у которой класс уже имеется, этот класс должен быть удален. Хочу посмотреть реализацию именно на jquery.
Большое спасибо!

```js
   $("white-btn").on("click", function(){
        var btn = $('.white-btn')
        $(btn).addClass('white-btn-active')
    });
```

```css
.white-btn{
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: var(--text);
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 6px 14px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.white-btn-active{
 color: #3f51b5;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #3f51b5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" sort-items">
     <span>Sort blog: </span>
     <div class="white-btn white-btn-active">all</div>
     <div class="white-btn">phorography</div>
     <div class="white-btn">lifestyle</div>
     <div class="white-btn">trip</div>
     <div class="white-btn">inspiration</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".white-btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".white-btn").removeClass('white-btn-active');
  $(this).addClass('white-btn-active');
});
```

```css
.white-btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--text);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.white-btn-active {
  color: #3f51b5;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #3f51b5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" sort-items">
  <span>Sort blog: </span>
  <div class="white-btn white-btn-active">all</div>
  <div class="white-btn">phorography</div>
  <div class="white-btn">lifestyle</div>
  <div class="white-btn">trip</div>
  <div class="white-btn">inspiration</div>
</div>
```